# no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1"

Tags: docker, minikube, kubeless

I have minikube v0.26.0 version and kubectl v1.10.1 version and localKube v1.8.0
i get the following error when i try to deploy the kubeless ui

```
$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeless/kubeless-ui/master/k8s.yaml
```

#### ERROR:

**unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeless/kubeless-ui/master/k8s.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1"**

Comment: Upgrade your cluster. Localkube is deprecated, and that version of minikube is nearly 2 years old. Now Deployments is in apps/v1 but back then was not.

Comment: `kubectl explain deploy`. Copy `apiVersion`.

Comment: can i just download the latest localkube 1.10.0 . this should work right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a long R & D

```
minikube start --logtostderr --v=0 --bootstrapper=localkube --vm-driver virtualbox
```

now it downloaded the latest localkube version, and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, you're using a version of Kubernetes that's very old. `Deployment` wasn't available under `apps/v1` until Kubernetes 1.9, and you appear to be using 1.8.

If you want to solve this problem without upgrading your cluster, you'll need to replace the `apiVersion` value in all of your `Deployment` objects with one of the older paths:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
```

Note that while this will fix the immediate problem, you will still likely run into other compatibility issues, and should upgrade your cluster.